# convert array of objects to map of field values structure javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const arr=[
{ name:"test",
  class:3
},
{ name:"test2",
  class:4
},
{ name:"test3",
  class:5
},]
```

Now I have to convert it to a map like structure as shown below:

```
const map={
"name":["test","test2","test3"],
"class":[3,4,5]
}
```

I am clueless on how to make this kind of structure.Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: iterate over the arr and push the data into map (btw would be better not using the name map to avoid confusion with .map belonging to arrays)

Comment: Are `name` and `class` fixed values? Are those the only properties? Will all objects always have both properties? If not, what would be the value for the resulting object in that case?

Comment: I tried iterating through them using map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an arbitrary amount of keys you can use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
 to get all the key value pairs. Then just loop over all entries and add them to the final output.

```js
const arr=[{name:"test",class:3},{name:"test2",class:4},{name:"test3",class:5}];

const map = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if(acc[key]) {
      acc[key].push(value);
    }else{
      acc[key] = [value];
    }
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a function that accepts the array and the property you're looking for, and return a new array of data using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for each property of your new object.

```js
const arr=[{name:"test",class:3},{name:"test2",class:4},{name:"test3",class:5}];

function getData(arr, prop) {
  return arr.map(obj => obj[prop]);
}

const map = {
  name: getData(arr, 'name'),
  class: getData(arr, 'class')
}

console.log(map);
```

Comment: What's wrong the answer?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like that

```
arr.reduce((res, obj) => {
   Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k,v]) =>     {
     if(!res[k]) res[k] = []
     res[k].push(v)
   })
    return res
},{})
```

Comment: yup it didnt work

Comment: Yes return should be outside the foreach. Im on mobile phone